# How to send a value of input data field to ajax file and update in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send `data-status` and `data-id` to update a comment table in my database with these values. Is it possible to send this value without a form to ajax file?

```html
<?php $status = ($row['comment_status'] == '1') ? "Hide" : "Show"; ?>                                                
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn1" class="pull-right btn <?php if ($row['comment_status'] == '1') echo "btn-success"; else echo "btn-danger"; ?>" value="<?=$status?>" data-status="<?=$row['comment_status']?>" data-id="<?=$row['comment_id']?>"/>
</p>
```

```js
$.ajax({
    alert();
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax-commentstatus.php',
    data: {
        status: $(this).attr('data-status'),
        comment_id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
    },
    dataType: 'html'
    success: function(data) {
        $("#msg").fadeIn().html(data);
        setTimeOut(function({
            $("#msg").fadeOut('slow');
        }, 2000);
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: show me the correct data-status and data-id input fields.

Comment: When you calling the ajax code ? Is it calling on form submit or calling on button click ? Add complete code here.

Comment: Your approach is fine, your problem is because you have quite a few syntax errors in your code. Check the console and fix the errors you see

Comment: I dont have any form here only this input field and need to send these value to ajax file

Comment: check your ajax call data definition ....

Comment: alert not working in $.ajax({})

Comment: Mr. McCrossan can you help me on this

Comment: anyone can help me